# runtime exception with providers - Ionic2 , Angular2 (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, angular, ecmascript-6, ionic2

I'm getting the following error when I try to run my ionic2 app (Typescript)

`ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for User! (BeerSearch -> User)`

Following is my code

```
#providers/beer_search/BeerSearch
import { User } from '../user/user';
......

@Injectable()
export class BeerSearch {
   constructor(private http: Http, user: User, config: Config) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Access-Token', user.getAccessToken())
  }
}

#providers/user/user
.....

@Injectable()
export class User {
  accessToken: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.accessToken = '<Some token>';
  }

  getAccessToken(){
    return this.accessToken;
  }
}
```

I cannot find what I'm doing wrong here , and this also **doesn't give any errors** with typescript in compile time. I'm getting this error only in runtime.

Comment: Did you provide the `User` service in the bootstrap call or the respective component?

Comment: hey @rinukkusu, thanks for the comment, but I'm calling a provider inside another provider , do I still have to add that to the component ? (Coz I added that to the component and still didnt work)

Comment: You can call services in services in services in services, if you want that. That's no problem at all. You just need to add them either to the `bootstrap` providers array or to root component's providers array. Otherweise they won't get resolved like you're just experiencing.

Comment: hi @rinukkusu, yep that was it :), I didnt know about that. thanks a lot. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it :), cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call services in services in services in services, if you want that. That's no problem at all. You just need to add them either to the `bootstrap` providers array

```
bootstrap(App, [..., User, BeerSearch]);
```

or to the root component's `providers` array.

```
@Component({
    ...,
    providers: [..., User, BeerSearch]
})
export class FooComponent { ... }
```

Otherweise they won't get resolved like you're just experiencing

Comment: Glad I could help! :)